# Update a column with Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I am new developing in SQL Server and I have no experience

I need help with a requirement, I have a table with 4 columns: FirdtName, LastName, Age and Profile, the requirement I have is: I need to develop a stored procedure, which goes through the records of the table one by one and depending on the value of the column Age, update the profile column, this means, for example if the age is between 16 and 20 years, update the Profile column with Junior, but if the age is between 21 and 35, update the profile column with Intermediate and so with each of the 100 records in the table.

Thank you very much for your help in advanse

Comment: Have you tried researching the issue on the Web before hand? This is what a stored procedure is: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp. I suggest you create a table with the required fields, and then write an SQL query to do what you need it to do, then create the stored procedure. This sounds like a homework problem. Try it out yourself first and if you get stuck, post the query for advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE DATABASE.ASSIGN_PROFILE  AS
      SELECT
        FIRSTNAME
        , LASTNAME
        , AGE
        , CASE
              WHEN AGE BETWEEN '16' AND '20'
              THEN 'JUNIOR'

              WHEN AGE BETWEEN '21' AND '35'
              THEN 'INTERMEDIATE'

              ELSE 'OTHER'
          END                                           AS PROFILE
      FROM
         DATABASE.TABLE
;
```

If all you need to do is populate the 'Profile' column based on conditions set by the value under the 'age' column... A case statement should allow you to do that.

Comment: Maybe you can try to structure your answer more clearly to make it easiert to understand